# Chrome extension button popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension to add a button to a particular page, and upon clicking that button, I want a popup to appear as shown on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup

I have used content script, I've included the css stuff from that link in a .css file, and I have a .js file for the content script that injects a button on the screen.

My button is appearing on the screen. What I want to know is, how do I get the popup as shown in the link to appear? They have used an html file in the link, but I am making changes in an already existing html page through a content script. So how do I go about it?

My .js file for content script:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
//button description

var body = document.getElementsByClassName("htmlclassname")[0];
body.insertBefore(button, body.childNodes[0]);
//Button appearing properly

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //What code do I put here to get a popup like in the link??????
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject all the DOM for your popup, as well as the button.

You can do this in the click event for the button:

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = 'Show Popup';
button.style.position = 'relative';

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(button);

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var popup = document.querySelector('#myPopup');
  if (!popup) {
    popup = document.createElement('div');
    popup.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    popup.style.width = '160px';
    popup.style.backgroundColor = '#555';
    popup.style.color = '#fff';
    popup.style.textAlign = 'center';
    popup.style.borderRadius = ' 6px';
    popup.style.padding = '8px 0';
    popup.style.position = 'absolute';
    popup.style.zIndex = '1';
    popup.style.bottom = '125%';
    popup.style.left = '50%';
    popup.style.marginLeft = '-80px';
    popup.innerText = 'A Simple Popup!';
    popup.id = 'myPopup';
    button.appendChild(popup);
  }

  if (popup.style.visibility === 'hidden')
    popup.style.visibility = 'visible';
  else
    popup.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

```html
<div>Content already in page.
  <p>blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Keith. This gets the job done, but upon a lot of research (I am new to all of this) after asking my question, I figured out a better solution is to create a div as `var div = document.createElement("div")` and add all of the content of button, popup as well as what I want inside the html as `div.innerHTML = " . . . "`. This way I can also use the css classes and selectors with ease!

Comment: @SaurabhShirodkar You can. Be careful though as the content security policy for the page may block inline CSS.

Comment: @Keith, this worked amazingly well. I was stuck on this for a while. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Getting Started: Building a Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) which shows how you can implement opening a popup window after clicking an icon. As mentioned in the given link, the actual logic of rendering the content of the popup is implemented by [`popup.js`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/tutorials/getstarted/popup.js).

Then, after you've got your first extension up and running, you can [fiddle your code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#update-code) with things exactly how you want it like setting a tooltip on the browser action button.

Tooltips can be set by specifying the `default_title` key in the manifest file. Open `manifest.json`, and add the `default_title` key to the `browser_action`. Make sure that the JSON is valid, so quote the key and add a comma where necessary.

Sample code:

```
{
  ...
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },
  ...
}
```

Suggested solution in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31380203) might also help.

Comment: This isn't what i am looking for. I do not mean the icon in the chrome bar, but an actual button which i'm injecting into the page's html after it loads via content script.